# Is there a way of doing a binary backup for Solr? Just like you do for mySQL?

Tags: solr

I was wondering if it is possible to do a binary copy of the Solr contents, in the very same way you can do it for mySQL, by copying the data directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solr Operations Tools suggested by @kmas are no longer supported. I would recommend using [Solr Replication](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication) for creating backups. You can either setup a Master/Slave configuration for backup purposes or leverage the backup feature of the Replication handler to create local backup copies of your data directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use the backup tool of SolR :
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrOperationsTools#backup